# How to prove that incidence matrix is totally unimodular

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization, total-unimodularity

> **Problem:** Prove that the incidence matrix $A$ of a graph define as follows: $$A_{ij}= \begin{cases}
>  -1 & \text{ if the edge } e_j \text{ leaves the vertex } v_i\\ 1 & \text{ if the edge } e_j \text{ enters the vertex } v_i\\ 0 & \text{
> otherwise} \end{cases}$$ is totally unimodular.

**My attempt:** Using induction on the size of the minor of $A$.

By the definition of the incident matrix $A$, all entries of $A$ belong to the set $\left\{-1,0,1\right\}$. Hence, every $1\times 1$ minor of $A$ belongs to $\{-1,0,+1\}$.

Suppose that every $k\times k$ minor of $A$ belongs to $\{-1,0,+1\}$, $k \ge 2$. We prove that it is the same for every $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ minors.

Let $B$ be a $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ submatrix of $A$. We want to prove that $\det(B) \in \left\{-1,0,1\right\}$.

Since each column of $A$ has at most 2 non-zero coefficients (because each edge is incident to at most two vertices), then either is $B$.

- **Case 1.** If a column of $B$ has 0 non-zero coefficients then $\det(B) = 0$.
- **Case 2.** If a column of $B$ has 1 non-zero coefficients, assume it is $b_{ij}$. Then, by Laplace theorem, we have
  $$\det(B) = b_{ij}(-1)^{i+j} \det(M_{ij}) = \begin{cases}
  (-1)^{i+j}\det(M_{ij}) &, \text{ if } b_{ij} = 1\\
  (-1)^{i+j+1}\det(M_{ij}) &, \text{ if } b_{ij} = -1
  \end{cases},$$
  where $M_{ij}$ is a $k \times k$ submatrix of $B$ obtained by removing row $i$-th and column $j$-th. Now, $M_{ij}$ is a $k\times k$ submatrix of $A$ and hence $\det(M_{ij}) \in \left\{-1,0,1\right\}$. It follows that $\det(B) \in \left\{-1,0,1\right\}$.
- **Case 3.** If a column of $B$ has 2 non-zero coefficients, assume that they are $b_{ij}$ and $b_{lj}$. Without losing generality, suppose that $b_{ij} = 1$ and $b_{lj} = -1$. Then, by Laplace theorem, we have
  $$\det(B) = (-1)^{i+j}\det(M_{ij}) - (-1)^{k+j}\det(M_{lj}),$$
  where $M_{ij}$, $M_{lj}$ are $k \times k$ submatrices defined as in case 2.

Now, I am stuck at the case 3. So, I wonder if there is another way to overcome this case.

**Edit:**
For more details, the context I am dealing with is the max flow problem
[image]

Comment: In Case $3$, you can assume all columns of $B$ has exactly two non-zero coefficients. But then the rows sum up to zero, so the matrix is singular and thus has determinant zero ?

Comment: @dezdichado I wonder why could we assume that? In addition, I also edited more detail in the post.

Comment: Typically, the columns correspond to edges and each edge enters exactly one vertex and leaves one vertex right ? Unless, you are using some other definition.

Comment: @dezdichado I use the same definition as you. But, the assumption all columns has exactly 2 non-zero coefficients does not always hold right?

Comment: Didn't you rule out case 1 and case 2 ? If not all of the $k+1$ columns has exactly two elements, then case 1 or case 2 is not ruled out and you get determinant zero.

Comment: @dezdichado I thought it just "there exists a column" to satisfy the condition we mentioned.

Comment: Think again - if any of Case 1 or Case 2 holds, we are done. So in that case that they do not hold, you have all columns of the submatrix you picked has at least two non-zero elements. But because this is the incidence matrix, it follows that $\textit{ each }$ of those columns will have precisely two elements $\{1,-1\}$ precisely. So sum of all rows become zero which means they are linearly independent.

Comment: @dezdichado Oh, I see. I will try to complete the answer and update it in this post. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition of the incident matrix $A$, all entries of $A$ belong to the set $\left\{-1,0,1\right\}$. Hence, every $1\times 1$ minor of $A$ belongs to $\{-1,0,+1\}$.

Suppose that every $k\times k$ minor of $A$ belongs to $\{-1,0,+1\}$, $k \ge 2$. We prove that it is the same for every $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ minors.

Let $B$ be a $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ submatrix of $A$. We want to prove that $\det(B) \in \left\{-1,0,1\right\}$.

Since each column of $A$ has at most 2 non-zero coefficients (because each edge is incident to at most two vertices), then either is $B$.

- **Case 1.** If a column of $B$ has 0 non-zero coefficients then $\det(B) = 0$.
- **Case 2.** If a column of $B$ has 1 non-zero coefficients, assume it is $b_{ij}$. Then, by Laplace theorem, we have
  $$\det(B) = b_{ij}(-1)^{i+j} \det(M_{ij}) = \begin{cases}
  (-1)^{i+j}\det(M_{ij}) &, \text{ if } b_{ij} = 1\\
  (-1)^{i+j+1}\det(M_{ij}) &, \text{ if } b_{ij} = -1
  \end{cases},$$
  where $M_{ij}$ is a $k \times k$ submatrix of $B$ obtained by removing row $i$-th and column $j$-th. Now, $M_{ij}$ is a $k\times k$ submatrix of $A$ and hence $\det(M_{ij}) \in \left\{-1,0,1\right\}$. It follows that $\det(B) \in \left\{-1,0,1\right\}$.
- **Case 3.** Every column of $B$ has exactly 2 non-zero coefficients, which are $-1$ and 1.
  Hence, the sum of all row vectors of the matrix $B$ equals to vector 0, i.e.,
  $$r_1 + r_2 +\ldots + r_{k+1} = 0 \in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}.$$
  Therefore, row vectors of $B$ are linearly dependent and it follows that $\det(B) = 0$.

In summary, we have prove that $\det(B) \in \left\{-1,0,1\right\}$ in all cases, or in other words, every $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ minors of $A$ belongs to $\left\{-1,0,1\right\}$. **(QED)**